# How do I connect three machines (one PC and two laptops) together though ssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, scp, multiple-computers

I am a student at a college and therefore am very limited over what I can do with routers and whatnot.  I need my PC tower to have ssh access to my school laptop and to my work laptop.  I need these laptops to communicate with each other and with the pc as well.  All of these machines have dynamic IPs, especially when I travel with either laptop.  Both laptops are windows. PC Tower is dual boot with windows and ubuntu however I use windows most of the time.  All three have SSH Client and SSH Server installed. Thanks Nerds!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What further details would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a peer to peer vpn network between the machines. You can explore **tinc**, you need to install it on all machines.

You need at least one known IP address that is accessible from all computers.

Answer (score -1):

If your devices can access to the internet, use [zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com/) or [remote.it](https://remote.it/).